# How to install windows mobile application software development kit (SDK)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I am having experience in Android and iPhone mobile application development.Now i want to start to learn Windows mobile application development.Please suggest some of the good tutorials for me and i am not having any .Net knowledge.

So Please give me any idea to download and install software development kit for Windows mobile apps development?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the SDK download link                                        http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find everything on 
http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/develop

Sdk is here:
http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Samples are here:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/

System requirement for emulator is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

One more link if you want is here it contains visual studio also with system requirement:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35471